# Unable to use 3rd party jQuery plugin typed.js in Angular 5

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, angular5

I am new in Angular. I am using Angular 5.

Here is my angular-cli.json file code snippet where I register my jQuery and typed.js script.

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/typed.js/lib/typed.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
  ],
```

In my header component I import jQuery and typed.js like below code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import Typed from 'typed.js';
```

When I want to activate the plugin using below code snippet:

```
 export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  options = null;
  typed = null;

  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.options = {
      strings: ['Grapich Designer', 'UI/UX  Designer'],
      typeSpeed: 40
    };
    this.typed = new Typed('.header-inner h6', this.options);
  }

}
```

And I am getting this error.

```
AppComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: typed_js_1.default is not a constructor
at HeaderComponent.ngOnInit (header.component.ts:21)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12369)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13893)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13836)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14729)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14670)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.html:12)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:14655)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13802)
at callViewAction (core.js:14153)
```

Comment: try to change the import of typed.js to this `import * as Typed from 'typed.js';`

Comment: thank you so much . for this i am stuck in there for two days :(

now it works

Comment: ... ....works ?

Comment: yes it worked fine.